# Getting notified of an Ineffective headers: Set-Cookie on one my sites

Tags: cookies

Can someone help me understand what constitutes my `Set-Cookie` header to be considered ineffective in a recent security scan?

When I view the cookie from the Header values, this is what I see:

```
wordpress_test_cookie=WP%20Cookie%20check; path=/
```

Is there a better practice for setting this cookie? It is a session cookie from WordPress

Comment: "ineffective" isn't a useful description of the problem. Find better security scanning software.